# How do I add a gradient hover over buttons in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have successfully added a gradient to navigation buttons in jQuery Mobile after finding some information on here. The problem I now have is adding a hover with gradient to the buttons. Any help will be gratefully received. Many Thanks. Below is my HTML & CSS:

```css
.color_tabs a {
  background-color: #0071bc !important;
  background-repeat: repeat-x !important;
  /* fallback */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#29abe2), to(#0071bc)) !important;
  /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #29abe2, #0071bc) !important;
  /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #29abe2, #0071bc) !important;
  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #29abe2, #0071bc) !important;
  /* IE 10 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #29abe2, #0071bc) !important;
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  text-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0.08em 0.08em 0px !important;
  border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
  border-bottom-color: #201F23 !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation Buttons   -->

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" data-theme="b">


  <div data-role="controlgroup" data-theme="d" data-type="vertical" class="color_tabs">

    <a href="map.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-text ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right" data-transition="slideup">Our Location</a>
    <a href="#about" class="ui-btn ui-btn-text ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right" data-transition="slideup">About Us</a>
    <a href="#weoffer" class="ui-btn ui-btn-text ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right" data-transition="slideup">We Offer</a>
    <a href="#service" class="ui-btn ui-btn-text ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right" data-transition="slideup">Service Check</a>
    <a href="#body" class="ui-btn ui-btn-text ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right" data-transition="slideup">Body Shop</a>
    <a href="#accservice" class="ui-btn ui-btn-text ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right" data-transition="slideup">Accident Services</a>
    <a href="#contact" class="ui-btn ui-btn-text ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right" data-transition="slideup">Contact</a>

  </div>
  <!--/ Navigation Buttons-->
```

Comment: I don't see any `hover` css. Have you even tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hover in the CSS

```
.color_tabs a:hover {
   background-color: #CCC !important;
   ...
   ...
   .. other gradients styles
}
```

Comment: is there a reason for all of the !important tags? have you tried to remove them? if you want to understand how important tags work in CSS, have a look at https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Also if you use the browser developer tools you will be able to see which styles are showing on hover

Comment: Yes, I tried it without an it didn't work, then I found that part of the css on here.   What it is you see, I have used Themeroller for the colour and because they've stopped using gradients I had to override it with that css I sent you to make it work.

Comment: can i have a look at your site?

Comment: Hi, it's not loaded on the server yet because it's not finished.

Comment: I could send you a screen shot though if that's any use?

Comment: This is weird, I've just loaded my site up in local google and the hover is working. I tried what you suggested last night and it didn't work...strange!

Comment: you can,but i'm not sure how much that will help.The only other thing i can think of without seeing the code, is that the hovers are being overwritten by JavaScript somewhere.

Comment: Guess it was the browser cache. Just for future use Shift + F5 in chrome to clear cache :)